# Releasing updates to Windows Services and Websites from build

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got an solution which consists of Windows Services and websites.  When updating the applications currently, the following steps are undertaken

1. Build of solution
2. Post build tasks copy the DLLs to a specific application folder
3. Build script is ran which gathers the DLLs relevant for each application (this is done via a text file containing a list of the DLLs per application, this needs to be changed if another DLL is added to the project). This is then stuffed in a release repository and pushed up to Github
4. Release repository is checked out on the server and a script is run to overwrite the DLLs and exes of both the Windows services and websites.  All of this is done via XCopy along with some Windows service commands to Start/Stop services.

I was wondering how to make this a bit easier? Or whether someone in a similar scenario does it differently?

Comment: software recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic] (it's the same here as at Stack Overflow). See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: You can ask for specific software recommendations at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's a combination of software and process recommendation

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

Yes because it would not be hard to fix the pain points in step 2 or 3 without much trouble -- just redo your packaging to call msbuild on individual projects with a desired output directory so you don't have to maintain the file lists at least.

Yes because you could probably dodge the whole github package by perhaps deploying your built artifiacts to the machine.

No because your deployment script is probably just about what you'd need for your one-off app and it is getting the job done and there might not be a better way to get there as most of the new toys are cloud-facing and windows services implies not cloud-facing.

You might also want to look at using something like teamcity or jenkins to orchestrate, record and otherwise manage the process.

Comment: Ahh do you use TeamCity for packaging DLLs after builds?

Comment: You could. You could also use teamcity to orchestrate the entire build process you've got laid out with good record keeping, reporting and notification.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for better tools, did you try to get most of the tools you already have? In our environment, we often create scripts for such a process, and (that is the important point!) **make them rock-solid**:

> Build of solution

You can do a build by calling `devenv.exe` or `msbuild` on the command line, so that's easily to put that into a script.

> Build script is ran which gathers the DLLs relevant for each application

Fine, already automatic. Make sure that script you mentioned here returns an error code in case it fails.

> This is then stuffed in a release repository and pushed up to Github

Should be simple to be scripted, using git from command line.

> Release repository is checked out on the server and a script is run to overwrite the DLLs and exes of both the Windows services and websites. All of this is done via XCopy along with some Windows service commands to Start/Stop services.

So already scripted - perfect.

To give this process a certain robustness, you have to make sure your script contains **full error checking** after each step, and display **which step failed** in case of failure. For example, call "devenv.exe", pipe the output to a `build.log` and use the `find` command to check if it contains the line "0 errors" (or something similar). After each step, always check `%ERRORLEVEL%` and stop if it becomes different from 0.